# reindexing json object into solr by adding only unique elements

Tags: solr, solrj

I have indexed json object into solr using httpclient
and when I tried to index again, duplicate records are getting indexed.

So how to update the records into solr,  everytime I index I want to update the records.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON Object include an ID field inside your json object and it should be unique, for example some random number like 65746 . When you will try to index this document again, solr will check for id .If id is same, solr will not index that whole document again . Now the question is how you declare a unique field in solr schema . So for that go to your schema.xml file or managed-schema file which is inside your core configuration and define unique field like this id . Now solr will identify id coming from your JSON as unique , and won't indexed already indexed documents.Hence there will be no duplicate records. Let me know if that helped you :)

Comment: what If I want to update some records in the document against that ID is it possible...

Comment: Yes that's possible ! ID will be one field , and then you can fields like title, content, email, description as per your need .

Comment: Will that be updated automatically...if not how..as I am new to solr so plz..let me know

Comment: Yes if you try to index that document again with that id only the field that you have updated will get update, it will not index the whole document and create a duplicate record. For example, if you changed title of of a document with id 557336 , only title gets updated, and only single document stays in index .I am working with Solr so i can tell that for sure . Please accept my answer if that helped you :) .

Comment: thanks for your answer It worked for me..This is the third time you helped me hope this will be continued.