# how to extract two json indexed documents separately using solrj or QueryResponse

Tags: solr, solrj, solr6

I have indexed two json documents into Solr, and when I get the response am I recieving both documents - how to differentiate the two documents and store the documents separately?

Comment: did not understand your question completely ! Is this related to any how related with uniqueness of documents  which i already answered here for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090847/reindexing-json-object-into-solr-by-adding-only-unique-elements/38091229#38091229 Can you elaborate ?

Comment: how to get the all the indexed documents as resultSet as we get in jdbc when we execute a sql query..as I need to add the fields to datatable as row wise..i hope you got it

Comment: please re-phrase your question correctly as it helps you find more good answers, btw i have posted my answer below .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a (unique) key when indexing the json-documents - this key being either mandatory or not. This could be done in schema.xml or managed-schema, if not already done. Further on would you have to search for this key in the query for fetching the wanted document.

This can be compared with querying for a unique primary key in SQL and traditional databases. A tuple/record, uniquely defined by the primary key, would in this scenario be equivalent with the json documents.

Assuming two documents with respective unique id 1 and 2 - can you fetch document 1 by searching for`q=id:1` in the Solr Admin-UI - if you want the document with id 1. I'm afraid I don't know how to do this is Solrj or by QueryResponse.

Management of where documents are stored in Solr is not supported - it is more or less black-boxed. This should however not be a problem considering your situation as long as you specify the query correctly.

Comment: how to get the all the indexed documents as resultSet as we get in jdbc when we execute a sql query..as I need to add the fields to datatable as row wise..i hope you got it –

Answer (score 0):

Look here for a link that tells how to use Solr 6 as a JDBC dataSource . Better if you use Solr 6 if you want to utilize Solr more as a data source  rather than an index source as it has enhanced SQL level features and hence, serves the purpose best . Here is the link https://sematext.com/blog/2016/04/26/solr-6-as-jdbc-data-source/ . Let me know if that helps you :) .